# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '200'

Tags: msg, mysql-error-1025

select * from Employee where salary < All (200,500)

Getting error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '200'.

Comment: What is your question? You may also want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980474/sql-any-all-operators

Comment: So did you read the documentation regarding the proper syntax for `ALL`? And what precisely do you expect `< All(200,500)` to do for you here?