# Rails: query that must match all terms

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've got the following model

```
class User

   # email String
   # name String
end
```

I want to be able to do a query that receives a search string and gives the users that match all of the terms. For example, let's say I've got the following user:

```
{ id: 1, name: 'John', email: 'john@email.com' }
```

If someone searched with `'Jo john@em'`, that would translate to two terms (`'Jo'` and `'john@em'`). In that case I'd like the user with id `1` to be returned. However, if someone submitted `'Joh mark@email.com'`, I don't want John to be returned, as one of the terms (`mark@email.com`) doesn't match either the name or the email.

The closest I've got to solve this is with this code (using the `squeel` gem)

```
terms = term.strip.split(' ').map { |term| "%#{term}%" }
User.where{ (name.like_any(terms)) | (email.like_any(terms)) }
```

where `terms` is whatever the user searched for. However, this only gives the users that match with at least one of the terms, not all of the terms.

I can, of course, get the results I want using several queries and using Ruby to my advantage, but I'd like to do it in just one query.

Just in case, I'm using PostgreSQL as my RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

[Squeel supports](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel#predicates) `&` 'and' operator as well as `|` 'or'.

```
User.where{ (name.like_any(terms)) & (email.like_any(terms)) }
```

Comment: This works for my example, but what if `User` had more columns, like `last_name`?

If the search were `'Joh john@em'` and `John` had `Williams` as his last name, then the query

`User.where{ (name.like_any(terms)) & (email.like_any(terms)) & (last_name.like_any(terms)) }`

wouldn't return John because his `last_name` doesn't match any term. I want all terms to be matched by any of the columns, not all of the columns to match any of the terms

Comment: Ah, so you are after something like the following pseudocode:
`columns = name, email, last_name
terms.all? {|term|
  columns.any? {|column| column.like_any term}}`
I'm just trying to imagine how the SQL would look for that and work backwards, not sure how Squeel works as I've not used it before.

Comment: [This answer gives hint as to how the SQL would look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5980661/193785). Simplest thing might be to have SQL in your query. Properly escaped of course.