# How to use ANY command in SQL

Tags: oracle

I have a following query description. How to express it in SQL?

> **Query** -> list all the employee first name such that their emp_pct is less than any of the employee whose proj_num is 18 (Make use of ANY).

I have following table name `EMP_2`;

```
Name                           Type
-----------------------------------
EMP_NUM                        CHAR(3)
EMP_LNAME                      CHAR(15)
EMP_FNAME                      CHAR(15)
EMP_INITIAL                    CHAR(1)
EMP_HIREDATE                   DATE
JOB_CODE                       CHAR(3)
EMP_PCT                        NUMBER(5,2)
PROJ_NUM                       CHAR(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go. The `ANY` keyword compares and short circuits the moment it finds a matching row in the sub-query.

```
SELECT a.EMP_FNAME 
FROM EMP_2 a
WHERE a.EMP_PCT < ANY (
  select EMP_PCT 
  from EMP_2 
  where EMP_NUM <> a.EMP_NUM and PROJ_NUM = 18);
```

Comment: See [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5980474/642706) for more discussion of `ANY`. And see [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html).