# How does the ALL selector work in SQL?

Tags: sql

I'm doing SQL Zoo and go stuck with this question:

List each continent and the name of the country that comes first alphabetically.

Here's a sample of the table:

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|    name     | continent |  area   |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| Afghanistan | Asia      | 652230  |
| Albania     | Europe    | 2831741 |
| Algeria     | Africa    | 28748   |
| ...         | ...       | ...     |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

the use of `ALL` in this case. Here's the solution:

```
SELECT continent, name
FROM world x
WHERE name <= ALL (
  SELECT name FROM world y
   WHERE x.continent= y.continent)
```

Is this saying to find the name where name is "smaller" then all of the values found in matching continents?

Comment: Yes, that is what it is saying.  More typically, this would be done without `ALL` and using `= SELECT MIN(name)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL ANY & ALL Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980474/sql-any-all-operators)

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I was confused why it wasn't using MIN(name). That just makes more sense to me.

Answer (score -2):

Does this not answer the question?

```
select continent
, min(name) "First Alphabetical"
from world 
group by continent
```

Comment: That query may or may not work for the SQL Zoo question, but it definitely doesn't work as an answer to the question that's being asked here. It would be useful commentary *in addition* to an answer though, so if you can edit this post, please do.