# What is the difference between ANY and ALL operators in SQL (in the below mentioned case)

Tags: sql

**Query 1** with **ANY** operator :

```
Select * from products
where price > Any (select price from products where price > 500)
```

**Query 2** with **ALL** operator :

```
Select * from products
where price > All (select price from products where price > 500)
```

Both Queries are same, the only difference is the change of operator.

**Query 1** is yielding me no results (0 rows)

**Query 2** is yielding me all the rows present in the table (77 rows)

I'm unable to understand the above phenomena, please help me in understanding these 2 queries.

Please refer to the sample data below:

**Product ID  ProductName   Price**

1            Mouse         10

2            Keyboard      21

3            CrossFit      45

4            Chair         123

5            Table         263

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL ANY & ALL Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980474/sql-any-all-operators)

Comment: Please do not tag spam. Narrow this down to one database.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for looking into my query but the link that you gave didn't help me solve the issue. Also, in the table there's  no entry where price >500 hence ALL returns false, so technically query2 should not print anything, but it's printing all the rows.

Comment: Why doesn't it help you, @Abhinavojha ? There are 5 answers on that question; are you saying *none* tell you the difference? The 2nd paragraph in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5980661/2029983) seems to explain succinctly.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for your prompt reply, I have a good understanding of both the operators but their behavior in the above queries is confusing me.

Comment: @Larnu, none of the questions in that post helped me understand that, they're not related to the problem I'm facing

Comment: What about it is confusing? For the first it must be true for *any* of the values and the latter *all* of them. If you aren't asking what's the difference (which is what your title asks) what *are* you asking?

Comment: @Larnu, I can perfectly understand my query with ANY, but why is it yielding all 77 rows in 'ALL' operator when there's no condition is true.

Comment: Without sample data, we can't answer that question, @Abhinavojha .

Comment: "*Both Queries are same*" -  no they are not

Comment: Hi @Larnu, the sample data is available on the website link that I've shared in question.

Comment: Provide the sample data in the question, @Abhinavojha , not an external site. This ensures the question is useful to future readers.

Comment: I would request you to please see that dataset, & try to understand the issue

Comment: Hi @Larnu, I have added a dataset with the question, also I'm able to understand perfectly the working of ANY & ALL but when we write this query : 

select * from products
where price > ALL (select price from products where price>500)

When we execute the inner query, it throws 0 rows as there's no product in the table which has a price>500, but when the whole query is executed, it throws all the rows.
I want to understand why the whole query is displaying all the rows when there's no product with price>500.

Comment: See my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From here [ANY/ALL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL):

> 9.23.4. ANY/SOME

...

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized subquery, which must return exactly one column. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each row of the subquery result using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ANY is “true” if any true result is obtained. The result is “false” if no true result is found (including the case where the subquery returns no rows).

> 9.23.5. ALL

...

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized subquery, which must return exactly one column. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each row of the subquery result using the given operator, which must yield a Boolean result. The result of ALL is “true” if all rows yield true (including the case where the subquery returns no rows). The result is “false” if any false result is found. The result is NULL if no comparison with a subquery row returns false, and at least one comparison returns NULL.

`select price from products where price > 500` returns no rows. So in `ANY` case:

> The result is “false” if no true result is found (including the case where the subquery returns no rows).

and in `ALL` case:

> The result of ALL is “true” if all rows yield true (including the case where the subquery returns no rows).

That means for `ANY` there be no matches from `products` and in `ALL` case all `products` match.